# Applying velocity on the x axis doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why

Tags: unity-game-engine

**SOLVED**

I'm leaving that here in case it helps anybody.
The probleme I had is that I was applying the force directly in the coroutine, not in FixedUpdate
So I just made a simple bool that if true in FixedUpdate would launch the function which applies the desired velocity.

---

So I'm making a 2D platformer in Unity for a month long jam and I'm having trouble with changing the x velocity.

Below is just for reference and the testing I did if that helps, there's a TLDR otherwise.

So for reference I have a basic character movement script, using rigidbody2D and changing the velocity directly.
The main feature is a recall, where I come back to a set point in time, but the problem is that I want my character to keep its velocity from before the recall.

It works absoluetly fine when I change the y velocity, but for some reason, changing the x value only very rarely leads to an actual movement, and I can't seem to  pinpoint what the instances where it works have in common.

I don't really know what to test, the code exectutes in its entirety every time, the rigidbody's velocity is changed, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

For testing,
I did a quick code to just change the x velocity with a click and it changes maybe 4 times out of 60 (while kinematic) at different intervals, despite being the seemingly only thing that changed.

In dynamic it works maybe 1 out of 10 times but at different intervals evey time too

It also only moves by 1 unit (x went from 0 to 1, 1 to 2 etc...) everytime.

I figured it would be because of friction, but it doesn't move wile in the air, or despite having a 2D physics material with no friction and changing my rigidbody to kinematic for a second when the impulse is supposed to happen.

i'm quite new to coding so sorry if it's a dumb question and thanks in advance :)

So here's the code for the recall and to apply the velocity at the end, it's kind of dirty work sorry.
I'll add the movement code in second and the impulse last
P.S : Recall works fine, even when changing the y velocity directly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;


public class Reset : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool _recallPointSet = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<Vector3> _positionList;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 _savedVelocity;

    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2D;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _impulse = 200f;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _rigidbody2D = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (_recallPointSet == true)
        {
            _positionList.Insert(0, transform.position);
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Recall") && _recallPointSet == true )
        {
            Recall();
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("SetRecall") && _recallPointSet == false )
        {
            SetRecall();
        }
        
    }

    private void SetRecall()
    { 
        _recallPointSet = true;
        
    }

    private void Recall()
    {

        _savedVelocity = _rigidbody2D.velocity;
        StartCoroutine(RecallTime(0.02f));
        _recallPointSet = false;
    }



    public IEnumerator RecallTime(float _delayBetweenFrame)
    {
        _rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;

        while (_positionList.Count > 0)
        {

            transform.position = _positionList[0];
            _positionList.RemoveAt(0);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_delayBetweenFrame);

        }

        //_rigidbody2D.velocity = _savedVelocity; - Using the line under for testing to remove variables

        _rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_impulse, _rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        //Debug.Break();
        //Debug.Log(_rigidbody2D.velocity);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        _rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;


        yield break;
    }

}
```

I'll also throw in the code for the movement just in case ( it works absoluetly fine)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody2D _rigidBody2D;

    [Header("Movement")]
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 10f;


    [Header("Jump")]
    [SerializeField]
    private float _jumpHeight;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _jumpCheckDistance;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _rigidBody2D = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(inputX * _speed, _rigidBody2D.velocity.y);

        inputX *= Time.deltaTime;

        _rigidBody2D.velocity = velocity;

        
        if (isGrounded() && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            Jump();

        }

    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        _rigidBody2D.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidBody2D.velocity.x, _jumpHeight);
    }

    private bool  isGrounded()
    {
        var floorTest = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, _jumpCheckDistance, LayerMask.GetMask("World"));

        return floorTest.collider != null && floorTest.collider.CompareTag("Ground");
    }

}
```